# Is there a scenario when you would put @Transactional to a method that only retrieves data?

Tags: java, jpa

For example this service class' method below:

```
@Transactional
public void findDiscountedItems() {
   List<Item> items = itemDao.findItems();
   List<Item> discountedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
   for (Item i: items) {
      if (isDiscounted(i))
         discountedItems.add(i);
   }
   return discountedItems;
}
```

Is there any scenario it would require this method to be @Transactional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you perform several read operations on the database and you care about consistency. You can apply more restrictive transaction isolation level to acquire read locks and avoid problems like *phantom reads*.

If you run only a single query, mark the transaction as `readOnly` or even skip the `@Transactional` altogether.

Comment: My officemate here, just said the same thing just now. The code I'm dealing with is not a simplified as my example, and in fact does have a retrieval sql that reads on several tables, some of which are tables used by another application (these 2 apps are sharing tables since 1 is a 'decorator' app of the other).

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, but in that case `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` would suffice, which can help the DataStore do an efficient batch of work.
['Isolation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) is a probably in this case the most important reason for using transactions.